# Conflict b/w datepicker and autocomplete jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

The below code works seperately in different php page. But when combining both in one page, nothing works. In firebug, the error says,

```
TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

$("#test1").datepicker({
```

**CODE FOR DATEPICKER**

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/date_pick/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="css/date_pick/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="css/date_pick/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#test1").datepicker({
      changeMonth:true,
      changeYear:true,
      yearRange:"-35:+0",
      dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy"
      });
      });
    </script>
<input type="text" name="test1" id="test1" />
```

**CODE FOR AUTOCOMPLETE**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/js/jquery.autocomplete.css">
<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/jquery.autocomplete.js "></script>
```

Comment: you have two same jquery library files loading in a page. Make sure and remove one instance of jquery.            
   <script src="css/date_pick/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>     
   <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
Remove one jquery file from any of the files.

Comment: Format your code please. It makes it easier to read and answer.

Comment: I removed "<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>". Now datepicker works and not autocomplete. Firebug error says ' $.browser is undefined'

Comment: Are you sure both `bootstrap/js/jquery.js` and `css/date_pick/jquery-1.10.2.js` are the same version? Make sure all your external scripts are loaded at the end of the page and the script block setting datepicket on `#test1` is right after that. Post the result.

Comment: how do i find the version?

Comment: Version is available in the first block of the file.

I think jquery.js will compatible for both. Remove the jquery-1.10.2.js and keep the "bootstrap/js/jquery.js" . Make sure this is the first Js file in the page and all other JS files should follow this jquery library.

Comment: If I remove ' jquery-1.10.2.js',nothing works and it gives two errors in firebug. "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" & "TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you have included 2 times the jQuery library.

```
<script src="css/date_pick/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

The jQuery library should be included once.

Comment: I removed "<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>". Now datepicker works and not autocomplete. Firebug error says ' $.browser is undefined'

Comment: Can you put some code on JsFiddle or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

can you try like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/date_pick/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/js/jquery.autocomplete.css">
<script src="css/date_pick/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="css/date_pick/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/jquery.autocomplete.js "></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#test1").datepicker({
  changeMonth:true,
  changeYear:true,
  yearRange:"-35:+0",
  dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy"
  });
  });
</script>
<input type="text" name="test1" id="test1" />
```

but I think it would be better to use a packed version of jquery UI so that you can call one file for each jquery UI component.

Also if you are getting $.browser is undefined error, I guess one of the UI libraries is outdated because it's calling a function which is deprecated in jquery v1.10.2